# Woodworking questions & plans

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I can't seem to find a wood working Stack Exchange site (nor on Area 51).

I'd like to ask how-to questions and ask and find woodworking plans for projects (like plans for a simple jewelry box).

Is the DIY site the place to go? Should I propose one on Area 51?

Answer (score 6):

[Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) accepts woodworking questions for things that will become part of a home (such as cabinetry, door or window trim, etc.).

For other questions, a [Woodworking Stack Exchange](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) site now exists.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these if you have no objection!

1. If you don't find no site that fits for your question, then yes! Propose it there. By going to area51 and first searching, nothing found go the category and at the end of the page propose for it and tell them the required information.
2. You can tell about this in

- https://diy.stackexchange.com/ if its about the goods in home, like a jewelary box for your wife :P (if any..)

That was the only site that I found from the current sites here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic, so that leaves one option to propose for it.

**What else you can do:**

You can support the proposal that is already present there, this way the more you support and the more it gets popular, the sooner it will get public! And you'll get a chance to ask the question to the site of your choice. Untill then you'll have to wait or you'll have to meld the question in a way that it fits the site terms.

Otherwise you can change the question and ask it to a relevant site, for example you can ask for a good decoration for a box in bedroom! Don't mention the jewelary thing or the wood.

Hope it helps.